# Understanding how plain integers are represented in Python

Tags: python, computer-science

While reading about Python's built-in types of number and specifically *integers*, I came across this line as quoted below;

> Plain integers are at least 32 bits long. The range is at least -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 (approximately
>   ±
>   2 billion).

Does it mean that any arbitrary number that I can think of which has 2 billion digits, is the limit for Python to display it as a *plain integer*? If I should ask more specifically, what does *"32 bits long"* mean in reference to the aforementioned quoted sentence.

Comment: You're misunderstanding. It's not 2 billion digits, it's a max *value* of 2 billion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not 2 billion digits, but the actual value of 2 billion.

The reference of **32 bit** represents the number of bits that python can store a plain integer into. Bits are represented in the base of 2 (because a bit can either be 0 or 1), where as our more common numbers in base of 10 are represented in the base of 10. The number 1 in the base 2 is 1, but the number 2 in the base 2 is 10 - just as in the base of 10, we go from 9 to 10.

The maximum value that can be stored in 32 bits are the number of combinations you can flip 32 ones or zeros. This will make the following number as `2^32` (=4 294 967 296). But you need to subtract 1 to get the maximum, because 0 is also a combination, making the largest unsigned number 4 294 967 295.

To represent also negative numbers the first bit is often reserved for signing the integer (1 means negative, 0 means positive) so it's *roughly* divided in half, making the smallest number -2 147 483 648 and the largest 2 147 483 647.

Comment: That makes so much sense to me now! Thank you for sharing that information.

Answer (score 2):

A bit is a small amount of computer space that can either store a 0 or a 1.

So, if I have 32 bits, I can represent numbers ranging from

00000...000 (32 zeros)

to

11111...111 (32 ones)

when written in [binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number).

The number with 32 ones is 4,294,967,295. Which means, in the simplest way, we can represent all numbers from 0 to 4,294,967,295. Now, in most situations, we want to represent negative numbers as well, so we divide the range of `0 to 4,294,967,295` by shifting it a little to go from `-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647`. (How this is done is in itself interesting, check out [Two's Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement))

So, the excerpt you've provided actually says that integers in Python are stored in 32 bits, which means an integer in python can be as small as -2,147,483,648 and as large as 2,147,483,647. (Beyond which it's treated as a bigint internally, which is stored in a different manner).

Comment: Thank you for sharing that information the concept makes more sense to me now.